What should be the specific configurations for a Jmeter master node when using 6 slave machines
Currently we are having a master node with windows OS having 8 GB of memory (6vCPU) and intel xeon CPU E5-2650 processor. This master is running with 3 linux slave machines with 8 gb of RAM each having same CPU. But when running the load test of 300 total users (with a throughput running at ~80k requests per min), master machine starts running hot and it does not generate the load further even when latency is good. Load starts reducing, so we were thinking to increase the infra for the master node and to increase the number of load generators. So want to know what should be the ideal specifications for master node to handle 6 slave machines. jmeter version is 5.6.3

We don't know the "ideal specifications" because it mainly depends on your test plan details, the throughput and JMeter results file configuration and your Sampler Sender configuration
Master machine doesn't produce any load, it just starts the test and collects test results and given you follow JMeter Best Practices and recommendations from 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure article you should handle 300 users without any issues with the described hardware specifications.
